# Sample Design for Kriging

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kriging, random, geostatistical-analyst, sampling

I am taking soil samples on an agricultural plot and will be using the results as input to create a semivariogram for kriging in ArcGIS. This plot features raised planting beds in which the test crop is planted. Ideally I am looking to take soil samples using a stratified random approach; with an equal number of samples collected from different management zones within the plot.

I am wondering whether **taking samples from the planting beds only** will result in valid output from the kriging process. Clearly, using this method, the sample points will be biased in their distribution; linearly, along the planting beds.

Will taking samples from the planting beds only result in a valid interpolation surface?

Comment: What have you tried?  Is there a specific concern about your result that you wanted to ask about?

Comment: Suggest you try asking on stats.stackexchange.com